# Program does not link to library even adding content of "pkg-config --libs" to $CFLAGS or $LDFLAGS

Tags: makefile, ld, autotools, configure, pkg-config

I am trying to compile a [program](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amsuite/files/ama/) which depends upon GLib's libgthread. The library is installed in my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) and `pkg-config` finds it:

```
$ pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0
-pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
```

I tried to run `configure` setting `$CFLAGS` with such output:

```
$ CFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0` ./configure
```

but it did not work:

```
$ make
[...]
gcc  -g -O2 -I/include -I/home/adam/fs//include -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -o ama [...] -lxml2
ama-ama.o: In function `main':
/home/adam/software/ama/src/ama.c:89: undefined reference to `g_thread_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: ** [ama] Erro 1
make[2]: Saindo do diretório `/home/adam/software/ama/src'
make[1]: ** [all-recursive] Erro 1
make[1]: Saindo do diretório `/home/adam/software/ama'
make: ** [all] Erro 2
```

I tried to set `$LDFLAGS`, too:

```
$ LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0` ./configure
```

and got the same error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct variable to set is `$LIBS`:

```
$ LIBS=`pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0` ./configure
```

Comment: With modern autoconf, it is generally preferred to do `./configure LIBS=$( pkg-config --libs gthread-2.0 )`, passing the assignment of LIBS as an argument to configure rather than setting it in the environment.

Comment: @WilliamPursell this seems much more reasonable to me but I did not know it. Thank you! It was worth to post this question only for this discovery.